# Pulling information from Google search query in top carousel

Tags: json, google-api, google-search

I know that fetching data from Google on a given search query is possible but what I can't figure out it how to query the top carousel. I believe each of the elements that are listed up there has a knowledge graph associated with each element.

Are these lists of elements something you can return in a JSON. If you type in "movies 2017" you will see what I mean. Each of those elements have knowledge graphs. I want the knowledge graph for each of the elements that might be listed there in a JSON. At worst return the titles of all the movies in this list to I can just a separate query for the knowledge graph.

[image: Image of what the search looks like]

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you look at custom search engine ?https://cse.google.com/cse/

Comment: Yes I have. The query doesn't return the rich snippets just the text results. Bing also does the same thing.